# 502 Bad Gateway Nginx Errors using Drupal 7

Tags: php, nginx, drupal-7

I am getting `502 Bad Gateway` error on my Drupal site. These errors appear intermittently.

I have tried increasing both `memory_limit` to 256M and `apc.shm_size` = 256M in php.ini , nonetheless the errors persist. Any suggestions?

I am using  an Aegir installation of Drupal.

Comment: Increase your php-fpm logging level and look for clues concerning max_children or segmentation faults.

Comment: Where can I increase the php-fpm logging level and where is the log file located?

Comment: Would these errors have something to do with it? 2013/06/03 03:18:09 [crit] 26295#0: unlink() "/var/lib/nginx/speed/c5/e4/e2/2f7cc0206de17d90908a7485a3e2e4c5" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2013/06/03 03:20:53 [crit] 26295#0: unlink() "/var/lib/nginx/speed/99/4b/59/9c13dfb673d6233f1d9f3ee8ab594b99" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2013/06/03 03:20:55 [crit] 26295#0: unlink()